# PyQt5 - Static QSettings variable lose it's value after first use and turns to None

Tags: python, pyqt5, python-3.6, qsettings

I'm facing a problem with a Python 3.6/7 project in PyQt5. In my main file I've something like this:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    ...

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setOrganizationName("ORGANIZATION_NAME")
    app.setOrganizationDomain("ORGANIZATION_DOMAIN")
    app.setApplicationName("APPLICATION_NAME")
    app.setApplicationVersion("APPLICATION_VERSION_CODE")

    SettingsUtils.initializeSettings()

    # Install translators
    ...

    value: list = SettingsUtils.getSettingValue("key")

    if len(value) == 0:
        window: Window = Window()
        window.show()

    ...

    # Run application until it terminates
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Then in the SettingsUtils class:

```
class SettingsUtils:
    __SETTINGS: QSettings = None
    __SETTINGS_FILE_NAME: str = "./mySettings.ini"

    @classmethod
    def initializeSettings(cls) -> None:
        cls.__SETTINGS = QSettings(
            QSettings.IniFormat,
            QSettings.UserScope,
            "ORGANIZATION_NAME",
            "APPLICATION_NAME"
        )
        cls.__SETTINGS.setPath(QSettings.IniFormat, QSettings.UserScope, cls.__SETTINGS_FILE_NAME)
        cls.__SETTINGS.setFallbacksEnabled(False)

    @classmethod
    def getSettingValue(cls, key: str, valueType: type) -> Any:
        if cls.__SETTINGS is None:
            raise Exception("Settings not instantiated")

        ...

        return cls.__SETTINGS.value(key, defaultValue, type=valueType)

    @classmethod
    def setSettingValue(cls, key: str, value: Any) -> None:
        if cls.__SETTINGS is None:
            raise Exception("Settings not instantiated")

        ...

        cls.__SETTINGS.setValue(key, value)
        cls.__SETTINGS.sync()
```

Inside the constructor of the class Window, that's a QWidget, to conclude, I use another couple of times the line `SettingsUtils.getSettingValue("key")`.

So, as you can see, I initialize the `__SETTINGS` static member of `SettingsUtils` class from my main script, then I use it to read a value from settings again from my main script, and then I use it again a couple of times inside the constructor of the `Window` class. The problem is that the `__SETTINGS` variable, when I first use it is correctly instantiated but when I read it again from `Window` constructor, that variable is resetted back to None. I think I'm missing something very stupid, but I cannot get what it is. Thank you all in advance.

Comment: provide a [MRE]

Comment: I do not reproduce your problem, so it is necessary that you provide an MRE

Comment: Hi @eyllanesc, I've managed to solve the problem: following your advice to build a reproducible example, I've realized that I can't. My code worked in mini example, so I realized that the error was in my code. Specifically, it was the way I was importing the `SettingsUtils` class: I've changed the line `from SettingsUtils import SettingsUtils` to `from utils.SettingsUtils import SettingsUtils` and all worked. It was like he was trying to load "another", un-initialized, settings utils class, is that correct? Btw, thank you for your help.